# windows server 2012 r2 can not connect to sql Data Access Manager

Tags: sql-server-2014

Any help please, am trying to run SunSystems Data Access Manager on my windows server 2012 r2 but i get the following error:
Client found  content type of text/html; charset=utf-8; but expeted text/xml'. The reques failed with the error message:--   The file '/SunSystemsReportServer/SunSystemsStudio.asmx' has not been pre-compiled.

Comment: Please move this question to https://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

i finally found a solution. The error was caused because the  SunSystems Reporting password was changed, i recovered the password and every went well. Thannks.